# Notifications in UIView Controller not firing

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiview, keyboard

I had this code working perfectly yesterday, and the only thing I've changed since then is setting another table view as the root table view and putting a segue from its cells into this VC, and suddenly now it's not working. Much thanks for anyone who can help out!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)
}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    guard let userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject] = sender.userInfo,
        keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size,
        offset: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size else { return }
    if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            })
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
        })
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    guard let userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject] = sender.userInfo,
        keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size else { return }
    self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you trace back to what you working had yesterday ...?

Comment: I did, it's included in the question.

Comment: Is `viewDidLoad` called?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the simulator is smart enough to know when you're using its keyboard and not. Protip, before freaking out about how your code stopped working, make sure you try it on a device first.

Comment: Oh haha, OK. Also, ⌘+K hides/shows the keyboard on the simulator. Might be helpful to get the results on the simulator as well.